# Can Javascript read the source of any web page?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on screen scraping, and want to retrieve the source code a particular page.

How can achieve this with javascript? Please help me.

Comment: Here is similar page you may get your answer as it solve my problem of getting the source of the HTML Page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367587/javascript-page-source-code

Comment: @mikenvck Why did you even mention PHP when the question was about JavaScript? The answers below show how to do this with JavaScript.

Comment: to get source of a link, you may need to use `$.ajax` for external links. here is the solution - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18447625/2657601

Comment: Not a single answer was native Javascript, all of them were jquery based.

Comment: jQuery is native JavaScript. It's just JavaScript you can copy from jquery.com instead of from stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 113):

Simple way to start, try [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

```
$("#links").load("/Main_Page #jq-p-Getting-Started li");
```

More at [jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

Another way to do screen scraping in a much more structured way is to use [YQL or Yahoo Query Language.](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/) It will return the scraped data structured as JSON or xml.
*e.g.*
Let's scrape stackoverflow.com

```
select * from html where url="http://stackoverflow.com"
```

will give you a JSON array (I chose that option) like this

```
 "results": {
   "body": {
    "noscript": [
     {
      "div": {
       "id": "noscript-padding"
      }
     },
     {
      "div": {
       "id": "noscript-warning",
       "p": "Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled"
      }
     }
    ],
    "div": [
     {
      "id": "notify-container"
     },
     {
      "div": [
       {
        "id": "header",
        "div": [
         {
          "id": "hlogo",
          "a": {
           "href": "/",
           "img": {
            "alt": "logo homepage",
            "height": "70",
            "src": "http://i.stackoverflow.com/Content/Img/stackoverflow-logo-250.png",
            "width": "250"
           }
……..
```

The beauty of this is that you can do ***projections and where*** clauses which ultimately gets you the scraped data structured and *only the data* what you need (much less bandwidth over the wire ultimately)
*e.g*

```
select * from html where url="http://stackoverflow.com" and
      xpath='//div/h3/a'
```

will get you

```
 "results": {
   "a": [
    {
     "href": "/questions/414690/iphone-simulator-port-for-windows-closed",
     "title": "Duplicate: Is any Windows simulator available to test iPhone application? as a hobbyist who cannot afford a mac, i set up a toolchain kit locally on cygwin to compile objecti … ",
     "content": "iphone\n                simulator port for windows [closed]"
    },
    {
     "href": "/questions/680867/how-to-redirect-the-web-page-in-flex-application",
     "title": "I have a button control ....i need another web page to be redirected while clicking that button .... how to do that ? Thanks ",
     "content": "How\n                to redirect the web page in flex application ?"
    },
…..
```

Now to get only the questions we do a

```
select title from html where url="http://stackoverflow.com" and
      xpath='//div/h3/a'
```

Note the *title* in projections

```
 "results": {
   "a": [
    {
     "title": "I don't want the function to be entered simultaneously by multiple threads, neither do I want it to be entered again when it has not returned yet. Is there any approach to achieve … "
    },
    {
     "title": "I'm certain I'm doing something really obviously stupid, but I've been trying to figure it out for a few hours now and nothing is jumping out at me. I'm using a ModelForm so I can … "
    },
    {
     "title": "when i am going through my project in IE only its showing errors A runtime error has occurred Do you wish to debug? Line 768 Error:Expected')' Is this is regarding any script er … "
    },
    {
     "title": "I have a java batch file consisting of 4 execution steps written for analyzing any Java application. In one of the steps, I'm adding few libs in classpath that are needed for my co … "
    },
    {
……
```

Once you write your query it generates a url for you

http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20title%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%22%20and%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Fdiv%2Fh3%2Fa'%0A%20%20%20%20&format=json&callback=cbfunc

in our case.

So ultimately you end up doing something like this

```
var titleList = $.getJSON(theAboveUrl);
```

and play with it.

***Beautiful***, isn’t it?

Comment: Brilliant, especially for hinting to the poor-man's solution at yahoo that eliminates the need for a proxy to fetch the data. Thank you!! I took the liberty to fix the last demo-link to query.yahooapis.com: it was missing a % sign in the url-encoding. Cool that this still works!!

Comment: Any idea how to scrape image and meta description from http://www.amazon.in/Xiaomi-Redmi-4A-Grey-16GB/dp/B01FM7K078?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=87MVWA5E1E8PEBZE8XZN&ref_=nav_custrec_signin&ref_=pd_rhf_gw_p_img_1 ?

Comment: query.yahooapis has been retired as of Jan. 2019. Looks really neat, too bad we can't use it now. See tweet here: https://twitter.com/ydn/status/1079785891558653952?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw

Answer (score 33):

Javascript can be used, as long as you grab whatever page you're after via a proxy on your domain:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="/js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$.get("www.mydomain.com/?url=www.google.com", function(response) { 
    alert(response) 
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Why is a domain based proxy required?

Comment: because of the Same Origin Policy

Comment: that's really interesting.  presumably there is some code to install on the server to make that happen?

Comment: @ejbytes: actually I think node.js has some modules.  I'm presuming OP wants to web scrape.

Comment: You will get a 'from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.' if you are not on the same domain though

Answer (score 8):

You can use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

```js
const URL = 'https://www.sap.com/belgique/index.html';
fetch(URL)
.then(res => res.text())
.then(text => {
    console.log(text);
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 7):

You could simply use `XmlHttp` (AJAX) to hit the required URL and the HTML response from the URL will be available in the `responseText` property. If it's not the same domain, your users will receive a browser alert saying something like "This page is trying to access a different domain. Do you want to allow this?"

Comment: Unfortunately, you won't receive any alert, it will just block the request

Answer (score 5):

As a security measure, Javascript can't read files from different domains. Though there might be some strange workaround for it, I'd consider a different language for this task.

Answer (score 4):

If you absolutely need to use javascript, you could load the page source with an ajax request.

Note that with javascript, you can only retrieve pages that are located under the same domain with the requesting page.

Answer (score 3):

Using jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$.get("www.google.com", function(response) { alert(response) });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You can't request a page outside of your domain in this way, you have to do it via proxy, e.g. $.get('http://mydomain.com/?url=www.google.com')

Answer (score 3):

I used [ImportIO](https://www.import.io/). They let you request the HTML from any website if you set up an account with them (which is free). They let you make up to 50k requests per year. I didn't take them time to find an alternative, but I'm sure there are some.

In your Javascript, you'll basically just make a GET request like this:

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  jsontext = request.responseText;

  alert(jsontext);
}

request.open("GET", "https://extraction.import.io/query/extractor/THE_PUBLIC_LINK_THEY_GIVE_YOU?_apikey=YOUR_KEY&url=YOUR_URL", true);

request.send();
```

Sidenote: I found this question while researching what I felt like was the same question, so others might find my solution helpful.

UPDATE: I created a new one which they just allowed me to use for less than 48 hours before they said I had to pay for the service. It seems that they shut down your project pretty quick now if you aren't paying. I made my own similar service with NodeJS and a library called NightmareJS. You can see their tutorial [here](https://hackernoon.com/nightmarishly-good-scraping-with-nightmare-js-and-async-await-b7b20a38438f) and create your own web scraping tool. It's relatively easy. I haven't tried to set it up as an API that I could make requests to or anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass the same-origin-policy by either creating a browser extension or even saving the file as .hta in Windows (HTML Application).

Answer (score 1):

Despite many comments to the contrary I believe that it is possible to overcome the same origin requirement with simple JavaScript.

I am not claiming that the following is original because I believe I saw something similar elsewhere a while ago.

I have only tested this with Safari on a Mac.

The following demonstration fetches the page in the base tag and and moves its innerHTML to a new window. My script adds html tags but with most modern browsers this could be avoided by using outerHTML.

```
<html>
<head>
<base href='http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/'>
<title>test</title>
<style>
body { margin: 0 }
textarea { outline: none; padding: 2em; width: 100%; height: 100% }
</style>
</head>
<body onload="w=window.open('#'); x=document.getElementById('t'); a='<html>\n'; b='\n</html>'; setTimeout('x.innerHTML=a+w.document.documentElement.innerHTML+b; w.close()',2000)">
<textarea id=t></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I use Safari 5.0.6 with webkit patches to update it to the equivalent of more recent versions. Which version of Safari did you use and what happened?

Comment: 8.0.3. Nothing happened other than some errors (which I didn't memorise) appeared in the console.

Comment: Which Safari are you using and what exactly were the errors?

Comment: Still 8.0.3 and if you really want me to reproduce the test case: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'w.document')`

Comment: The most likely explanation for what you've managed to do is that you've found a security hole that exists thanks to some combination of your positively ancient browser and the unofficial patches to it. That isn't something of practical use in most cases.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your 8.0.3 - works in all my browsers except Firefox - I Googled your error and found 3 possibilities: popups not enabled, sometimes a delay is needed for the page to populate the popup, there is a documented webkit bug about this issue - I did my original testing locally and have just noticed that it does not work on my server - did you test locally or on a server?

Comment: On a server. Local files don't reflect typical web development.

Comment: I apologise for not making it clearer at the outset - it is probably still a useful device and it still demonstrates an exception to the same origin restriction - I will investigate its possible use on a server - does it work locally for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
javascript:alert("Inspect Element On");
javascript:document.body.contentEditable = 'true';
document.designMode='on'; 
void 0;
javascript:alert(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

Highlight this and drag it to your bookmarks bar and click it when you wanna edit and view the current sites source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a XmlHttpRequest and request the page,and then use getResponseText() to get the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to get a file, and when selecting a file, put the url of your web page into the selection box.
Use this code:

```
function readFile() {
    var f = document.getElementById("yourfileinput").files[0]; 
    if (f) {
      var r = new FileReader();
      r.onload = function(e) { 
        alert(r.result);
      }
      r.readAsText(f);
    } else { 
      alert("file could not be found")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery is not the way of doing things.
Do in purre javascript

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
    r.open('GET', 'yahoo.comm', false);
    r.send(null); 
if (r.status == 200) { alert(r.responseText); }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $.getJSON('http://www.whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('hhttps://example.com/') + '&callback=?', function (data) {
        alert(data.contents);
    });

</script>
```

Include jQuery and use this code to get HTML of other website. **Replace example.com with your website**.

*This method involves an external server fetching the sites HTML & sending it to you. :)*

Answer (score 0):

On linux

1. download slimerjs (slimerjs.org)
2. download firefox version 59
3. add this environment variable: export SLIMERJSLAUNCHER=/home/en/Letöltések/firefox59/firefox/firefox
4. on slimerjs download page use this .js program (./slomerjs program.js):

   ```
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.open(
     'http://www.google.com/search?q=görény',
      function() 
      {
        page.render('goo2.pdf');
        phantom.exit();
      }
    );
   ```

Use pdftotext to get text on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const URL = 'https://wwww.w3schools.com';
    fetch(URL)
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(text => {
        console.log(text);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));










    const URL = 'https://www.sap.com/belgique/index.html';
    fetch(URL)
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(text => {
        console.log(text);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```