# How do I get the HTML source from the page?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to access the page HTML source code using javascript?

I know that I can use `document.body.innerHTML` but it contains only the code inside the body. I want to get all the page source code including head and body tags with their content, and, if it's possible, also the html tag and the doctype.
Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the entire document HTML as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817218/how-to-get-the-entire-document-html-as-a-string)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

or

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

Comment: i don't know why in Firefox the document.documentElement object doesn't have the outerHTML property, but with the innerHTML i can get almost everything except the doctype so thank you!

Comment: @mck89: no browser but IE will have `outerHTML`.

Comment: Be aware that the source you get with Firefox/most browsers is the "true" source you served up.  In IE you will get the "live" HTML of the page including any changes the user has made to forms, any new DOM content etc.  In IE it will also be the mixed case invalid tag soup that IE provides when requesting the .innerHTML of elements.

Comment: In case anyone else is still looking into this, the situation has changed somewhat. @Crescent Fresh was correct 2 years ago, however more recent versions of Chrome and Safari also implement HTMLELement.outerHTML - though at the time of writing, Firefox does not.

Comment: @LiamNewmarch 2 years after your comment, which was 2 years after the initial post, and it seems that now Firefox also implements outerHTML. :)

Comment: This is the current state of the DOM not the source code.

Answer (score 19):

This can be done in a one-liner using [*XMLSerializer*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XMLSerializer).

```
var generatedSource = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document);
```

Which gives *String*

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>

<title>html - javascript page source code - Stack Overflow</title>
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately you will get garbage if the document content has any character that requires escaping in XML. Also you will not get the real original string but something slightly different (e.g. including an XML schema link).

Answer (score 11):

One way to do this would be to re-request the page using [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest), then you'll get the entire page verbatim from the web server.

Comment: Note that servers do not necessarily respond in exactly the same way to two individual requests.

Answer (score 3):

For IE you can also use:

```js
document.all[0].outerHTML
```

Comment: Surprised this isn't marked as the answer. This works perfectly! The only thing is it only gets static HTML (doesn't retrieve anything javascript-related).

Answer (score 2):

Provided that

- true html source code is wanted (not current DOM serization)
- and that the page was loaded using GET method,

the page source can be re-downloaded:

```javascript
fetch(document.location.href)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(pageSource => /* ... */)
```

Comment: That is unreliable because there is no guarentee that the server will serve the same content next time.

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski Given that the REST protocol is defined as [stateless](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34130036/9063935), as long as you send the same headers in the ajax request as the browser did, then I would be confident the server would send the same response.

Comment: @dantechguy What are you talking about? There is nothing in the OP about REST. Whether an endpoint is a REST one depends on the server. The `fetch` API is typically used by client-side JS to talk to REST endpoints, but using the `fetch` API on a non-REST endpoint doesn't magically turn it into a REST one. But even if we talk REST, statelessness is irrelevant. Two identical REST GET requests can return different data if the resource was actually modified between the requests, or your permission to access the resource was revoked, or for a number of other reasons.

Comment: You make this a bit more reliable by at least adding an `Accept` header similar to that of the browser. But yeah, this approach is not generally reliable.

Comment: This worked for me! this youtube url has timedtext (transcription) in 'view page source' and could only retrieve this by fetching the url again. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LA-LMRFhzaw&ab_channel=jordifieke