# Send html snapshot to server using client side javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to send the fully generated  html code of its own web page using javascript. For example, at a button click event, the current html code of the page is sent back to the server. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery, this should do that for you:

```
$("html").html()
```

And if you really need the HTML tags:

```
function getPageHTML() {
  return "<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>";
}
```

Even:

```
$('html')[0].outerHTML
```

Comment: Author was asking the functionality in raw javascript.

Comment: And I supplied an alternative, though your answer is probably more fitting. Either way, it still might help him.

Comment: :) actually speaking the jQuery approach is what i feel the best, anyway you cant use jQuery lib if its of no use.

Answer (score 0):

you can access the source code this way

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML/innerHTML
```

**REF:**
[How do I get the HTML source from the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367587/javascript-page-source-code)

Happy Coding :)