# How to get a value from page source code from a function tag?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, object, attributes

here is the function from the source code

```
function dosubmit()
  {
    if (getObj("Frm_Username").value == "")
    {
      getObj("errmsg").innerHTML = "Username cannot be empty.";
      getObj("myLayer").style.visibility = "visible" ;
      return;
    }
    else
    {
      getObj("LoginId").disabled = true;
      getObj("Frm_Logintoken").value = "3";
      document.fLogin.submit();
    }
  }
```

i want to get the value of getObj("Frm_Logintoken") as i can't pull the value
 from  #Frm_Logintoken

using `document.getElementById("#Frm_Logintoken")` this gives me null

because Frm_Logintoken only gets it's value when i click submit .

```
<input type="hidden" name="Frm_Logintoken" id="Frm_Logintoken" value="">
```

full [page code](https://www.pastiebin.com/5cfb6678510df)

i found this online `/getObj\("Frm_Logintoken"\).value = "(.*)";/g` but when i run it ... it gives me the same line again ! it's [full code](https://www.pastiebin.com/5cfb66be55bb9)

another regular expression i found but don't even know how to use it

> Example of a regular expression to search:
>   before_egrep='*N1*:getObj("Frm_Logintoken").value = "(\w+)"'
>
> Here, *N1* is assigned the value of the back reference - the
>   expression in parentheses. \w + denotes the main compound characters,
>   this is a synonym for "[_[:alnum:]]". Once again - pay attention to
>   the brackets - this is the back link. At the same time, there are also
>   parentheses in the source code fragment - they need to be escaped

i am trying to make an auto login script that works in the background like it

doesn't show the user the login form page but the only the page after it

and i have found this code online too but don't know what's about
it [contains xhr](https://www.pastiebin.com/5cfb66be55bb9) .

the line that Attracted my attention is

```
/getObj\("Frm_Logintoken"\).value = "(.*)";/g
```

when i run it ... it gives me the line again !

some notes :

i have tried document.getElementById("Frm_Logintoken").value but it gives me empty "" because

> Frm_Logintoken only gets it's value when i click submit .

the page will not even accept the correct password if the Frm_Logintoken token value isn't the same as one in the page.

the Frm_Logintoken is a token generated by the page and it basically increment by one on each successful login.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about suggestion of an expression for helping or ameliorating to help solving your problem, yet if we wish to extract certain attributes and values from the proposed `input` tag, we would be likely starting with an expression similar to:

```
name="(.+?)"|id="(.+?)"|value="(.+)?"
```

which uses alternation to simultaneously collect values of certain attributes, if so would be desired.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KlqGgM/1/)

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired and you wish to modify it, please visit this link at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/KlqGgM/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: thanks but i don't want the value from the input tag but from the function dosubmit() tag

Comment: this line exactly
       `getObj("Frm_Logintoken").value = "3";`

Comment: Wouldn't this just match all the lines that doesn't contain new lines ?

any way can we get a one to match this  `getObj("Frm_Logintoken").value = "3";`

?

Comment: i found that `getObj\("Frm_Logintoken"\).value = "(.*)";` works as expected but how can i get the value of the result group 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

To get your value you might use a capturing group `([^"]+)` and a negated character class:

```
\bgetObj\("Frm_Logintoken"\)\.value = "([^"]+)";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GSB7r6/1) | [Javascript demo](https://ideone.com/UT7w9T)

For example:

```
let str = `getObj("Frm_Logintoken").value = "3";`;
let pattern =/\bgetObj\("Frm_Logintoken"\)\.value = "([^"]+)";/;

console.log(str.match(pattern)[1]); //3
```

Comment: your answer is good but i think i asked the wrong question ... i need to make an auto login script  so i need the script to find the value for me .. so let str isn't possible in my case !
what should the title of my question be ?

Comment: @minanageh Not sure where your jacascript is located but perhaps you could check [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367587/how-do-i-get-the-html-source-from-the-page) to get the html of the current page instead of `let str`.

Comment: ok i will check it .. my java script should be  located  on a local web server with the ip of something just like 192.168.1.22

Comment: i got how to make it work if it's the same page 
`let str = document.documentElement.innerHTML` 
then your code
`let pattern =/\bgetObj\("Frm_Logintoken"\)\.value = "([^"]+)";/;`

`console.log(str.match(pattern)[1]);`

but if it's from another page ?

Comment: That depends where that page is. If it is on the same domain and allowed you might try an asynchronous call to get the page and get that html.

Comment: it's not the same range of ips

Comment: how can i do an asynchronous call  ?

Comment: You could check [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery) on how to do that.

Comment: mate i tried this code cause the one in that link isn't clear enough !.
`<object type="text/html" data="http://192.168.1.26/" ></object>

<script>

let str = document.documentElement.innerHTML
let pattern =/\bgetObj\("Frm_Logintoken"\)\.value = "([^"]+)";/;
console.log(str.match(pattern)[1]);

</script>`
but it doesn't work cause the it page code didn't change with the new code !

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://192.168.1.26/", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

let str = document.documentElement.innerHTML
let pattern =/\bgetObj\("Frm_Logintoken"\)\.value = "([^"]+)";/;
console.log(str.match(pattern)[1]);

</script>

</body>
</html>
`
tried this from your link  doesn't work !

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>

httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
httpRequest.open('GET', 'http://192.168.1.26/')
httpRequest.send()
 
 let str = document.documentElement.innerHTML
let pattern =/\bgetObj\("Frm_Logintoken"\)\.value = "([^"]+)";/;
console.log(str.match(pattern)[1]);

</script>

</body>
</html>
`
i got the working one but .
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: That is what I meant with if it is allowed. You can find resources online how you might enable that also if you are allowed.

Comment: but the response of the page doesn't have any thing about Access-Control-Allow-Origin !!! what about the object type is there any to get the value using it ?