# how can I get the results of group 1 of a regex match in java script while I can't declare the string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, token, declaration

here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KlqGgM/3)

the REGULAR EXPRESSION

```
getObj\("Frm_Logintoken"\).value = "(.*)";
```

this the TEST STRING

```
getObj("Frm_Logintoken").value = "3";
```

i want to get that number only "3" without quotes

it's in the Group 1 of the matches but i don't know how to get it from that group .

i can't var myString = "something format_abc";

because i am doing this to get the value that i don't know !!

And testing this in console results

var test = /getObj("Frm_Logintoken").value = "(.*)";/g

undefined

console.log(test[1](https://regex101.com/r/KlqGgM/3)); 
undefined
undefined

[the same question but in a different way and detailed still unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56503127/how-can-i-use-a-regular-expression-in-java-script-to-get-a-value-from-page-sourc)

i have tried

```
getObj\("Frm_Logintoken"\).value = "(.*)";`.match(/getObj\("Frm_Logintoken"\).value = "(.*)";/)[1]
```

it give me this "(.*)" not the wanted value !!!

some notes

1-that value isn't static

2- i want to make the code works automatic so fetching the line "getObj("Frm_Logintoken").value = "3";"
from the page code manually  is unwanted thing.

3- i want to make an auto login script without any User intervention.

4- if you still don't understand the question see the links pls

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression)

Comment: @CodeManiac it's not i have already looked there and found no suitable answer !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you must declare the string first !**

so if you are trying to get the value from the current page html code you can just

```
let str = document.body.innerHTML;
let pattern =/\bgetObj\("Frm_Logintoken"\)\.value = "([^"]+)";/;
console.log(str.match(pattern)[1]);
```

and if you are trying to fetch the  html string from other page using something like XMLHttpRequest

you can do this

```
let str = (http.responseText);
```

the full code :

```
const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = 'http://page/';
http.open('get', url, false);
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  http.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(http.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(http.status === 200 || http.status == 0)
            {
                let str = (http.responseText);
                let pattern =/\bgetObj\("Frm_Logintoken"\)\.value = "([^"]+)";/;
                let results = str.match(pattern)[1];
                    console.log(results);
            }

        }
    }

http.send();
```

Hope you understand and make a Clearer question next time and write your really point of the question and the use of the wanted fix .

Answer (score 0):

You can access group by accessing index of matched value

```js
let str = `getObj("Frm_Logintoken").value = "3";`

let op = str.match(/getObj\("Frm_Logintoken"\).value = "(.*)";/)

console.log(op[1])
```

Comment: dude haven't you seen this in the post ?
"i can't var myString = "something format_abc";

because i am doing this to get the value that i don't know !!"

????
how i do var it while i don't even know it's value !!!!!!! i am trying to get it !!

Comment: @minanageh well how does that makes any difference, instead of keeping in variable you can directly do `'getObj("Frm_Logintoken").value = "3";'.match(/getObj\("Frm_Logintoken"\).value = "(.*)";/)`

Comment: yes it make .....
if there is a one that i don't write the value in this what i need to grab the value from the page source code from the line 
getObj("Frm_Logintoken").value = 

............... if this possible 'getObj("Frm_Logintoken").value = "gets me the value from the exact line before equals sign from the page sorce code";'.match(/getObj\("Frm_Logintoken"\).value = "(.*)";/) ............

is this clear enough ? if i set the value by myself then why the ... i don't use that number directly in the auto login code ?!