# how can i inspect(document.body) in js while loading the page using object?

Tags: javascript, string, object, domdocument

i tried to load the page using XMLHttpRequest() but i got

> blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource

so i tried to load the page using something else so i used

```
object type="text/html" data="http://page/"></object>
```

it loaded the page in a small box .
so i tried to define the page code to a constant so i be able to find a value from it's code using

```
let str = document.querySelector("body")
```

but it selected my page body not the page loaded using object .
i tried the querySelector because

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

have the same problem. if there a way to inspect elements to the correct page it would solve this .
the page and console before inspecting the wanted area manually

[image]

the page and console after inspecting the wanted area manually

[image]

note: i can't edit the requested page

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to do but regarding the CORS issue you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-pr

Comment: "what you are trying to do" i am trying to get the value that's used to login to make an auto login script ..
the link doesn't help a lot cause i am not using php or node !

Comment: i just want to get it working using this object  method !

Comment: @Yaki for more info about what i am trying to do .
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56503127/how-to-get-a-value-from-page-source-code-from-a-function-tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can't because objects ( Iframses ) have the cross domain policy too**