# Getting page Details from its address using javaScript(Ajax)

Tags: javascript, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Javascript read the source of any web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680562/can-javascript-read-the-source-of-any-web-page)

Can somebody please guide  me to write a javascript snippet that fetches page details i.e page title,body content,and images just from link.

Well i have wrote a javascript that fetches source code from the posted link.I can always use getElementBytagName to get the required tags.I just wanted to know if there is a better way to do so.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function changed(obj)
{
   get_information(obj.value);
}

function get_information(link) 
{ 
var xhr
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xhr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhr.open("GET", link, true); 
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
if (xhr.readyState === 4) 
{ 
alert(xhr.responseText); 
} 
};
 xhr.send(null);
 } 


</script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="text" onchange="changed(this)"/>
</body>
</html>
```

---

no i dont want the same page to be edited,i need to fetch the other page details from its link

Comment: You can't do this with a "JavaScript snippet", but you might want to look into YQL.

Comment: may be this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680562/can-javascript-read-the-source-of-any-web-page) will help :)

Comment: What "details" are you trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to get the title/body/content/images on the current page?

Something like this may work:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>fetch</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showtitle(){
            var title=document.getElementsByTagName('title');
            alert(title[0].innerHTML);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span onclick="showtitle();">get</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Otherwise if you want to retrieve a new title/body/etc and update the page without reloading, you will have to use some sort of ajax request. Perhaps [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [the ultimate ajax object](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Ultimate_Ajax_Object).