# How to download a webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Javascript read the source of any web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680562/can-javascript-read-the-source-of-any-web-page)

I want to download a file using javascript and parse it. I need a function like php's `file_get_contents()`. I looked for it, but I couldn't find anything.

Update: Thanks for solutions, but I forgot to write that AJAX doesn't suite this problem, because I don't have any access to the remote address and have cross-domain requesting problem. I can't setup any php proxy either, because my host blocks access to fopen. I would prefer a pure javascript solution.

PS: Sorry, but the question was really a duplicate (I didn't know that) and the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680562/can-javascript-read-the-source-of-any-web-page) perfectly suits this problem.

Comment: Do you want to download a file or a webpage?  A webpage is a set of multiple files.  Also what context do you want the code in.  A browser plugin, a webpage script or a server side javascript?

Comment: What happened to the good old XMLHttpRequest??

Comment: @Caimen: I want to download an HTML file. By that means, it's only a file, because I just need to parse it and I don't need the styling, etc.

Answer (score 8):

Look into the XMLHttp Request

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp

or the load, $.get, $.post and $.ajax methods of JQuery.Here is a sample

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
request.open("GET", 'http://www.url.com');
request.onreadystatechange = function() { 
if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {

//response handling code

}
};
request.send(null); // Send the request now
```

Comment: two things: [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/) and [some real documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: yep but i dont think beginners would read documentation. I don't know bout you. But w3schools got me started.
Hell, I am going to the documentation link, thanks .

Comment: beginner's should absolutely read documentation.

Comment: well i have tried that with php when i was 17, it all looked like french.

Comment: that's because [it's php](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/) ;)

Comment: dude it says i-love-php here :D

Answer (score 4):

Short question, short answer: You probably want to play around with some Ajax. Either by calling a local php script making a `file_get_contents()` and returning it the the page, or directly calling an external URL. Your browser might not allow you to do this though.

**Added:**
You updated your question saying you *prefer a pure javascript solution*. I don't think you can since you're trying to fetch something that is not [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). 
Also, you say your host blocks `fopen()`, I used to be on a hosting where they did the same. I was surprised to find they did NOT block the [use of sockets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php), here's my workaround:

```
$server = "www.example.com";
$path = "/path/index.html";
$type = "HTTP/1.1";

$fp = fsockopen($server, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
else {
    $out  = "GET $path $type\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: $server\r\n";
    $out .= "User-Agent: Mozilla 4.0\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    $contents = "";
    while (!feof($fp)) $contents .= fgets($fp, 128);
    fclose($fp);
    echo $contents;
}
```

I realize you didn't want a PHP proxy solution, I think you might have no other choice. Give it a try, works great for me. If your hosting also is blocking `fsockopen()` you might be out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest). It asynchronously downloads a file from the web.

If you plan on using `jquery`, have a look at .ajax(), which wraps XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 1):

**Iframe:**
Place an invisible iframe on your page,

```
<iframe id="frame1" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

Trigger a download [click or some other eventt handler etc], and set the URL of the Iframe.
For example , `"/location/file"`

```
var iframe =  document.getElementById("frame1");
iframe .src = "/location/file";
```

This will trigger download from the browser.

Another approach will be to to simply navigate to the download url, browser figures out that MIME type cannot be displayed and will present a download dialog. Use

```
window.location.href = "/location/file";
```

Comment: `What if it's an HTML file?`