# Check if the webpage a href points to contains certain text

Tags: javascript, html, href

I would like to know a way to check if the webpage a href points to contains certain text using javascript.

```
<a href="/path/to/document.html" onclick="check_page()">click</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function check_page()
    {
        //check for text in /path/to/document.html        }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you looking for text in the URL itself, or in the document that the URL points to?

Comment: Text in the actual html file it points to

Comment: if it is pointing to a webpage in the same domain you can use ajax to load the page as text and find what you are looking for

Comment: Maybe this question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680562/can-javascript-read-the-source-of-any-web-page

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>

function check_page(url){

if (url.href.indexOf("/path/to/document.html")>-1){ 
alert('error');
}
}
</script> 
<a href="/path/to/document.html" onclick="javascript: return check_page(this)">test</a>
```