# How do I extract data from a website using javascript.

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-crawler

Hi complete newbie here so bear with me. Seems like a simple job but I can't seem to find an easy way to do this.

So I need to extract a particular text from a webpage "www.example.com/index.php". I know that the text would be available in p tag with certain id. How do I extract this data out using javascript?

What I'm trying currently is that I have my javascript file (trying.js) on my computer with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get("www.example.com/index.php", function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    }) ;
});
```

and a html that runs the javascript file.

When I open this html page with firefox it doesn't show me anything in console. How do I get the website's data? Am I on the correct track here? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can't, javascript has a same origin policy, so you don't have access to other websites than those on the same domain or services that support JSONP or CORS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Javascript read the source of any web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680562/can-javascript-read-the-source-of-any-web-page)

Comment: You need to write an app, maybe using `Selenium` or `Watin` browser automation or my new favorite CSQuery (it has only read access to the DOM but uses JQuery style filters in CSharp and is really fast).

Comment: What you're looking for is a page scraper. Javascript can't pull it off because it can only gather data from the domain you're on. You could build it in Ruby, for example, and use one of the many existing gems for this sort of task, like https://github.com/assaf/scrapi or http://nokogiri.org/

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680562/can-javascript-read-the-source-of-any-web-page There are multiple ways discussed. Hope it helps you.

Comment: @adeneo client-side javascript that is the case, JavaScript runs in many different places, for example node.js does not have browser access-policy restrictions.

Comment: @balupton  - I sort of assumed it was clientside, as the OP was specifically using jQuery and Firefox, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @adeneo yeah no worries, was just clarifying the use of JavaScript there. 