# How to get a page source using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the page source for any url using javascript. Can any one help me? I need a full html code for this.

Comment: is there anything you have tried to achieve this? SO is not a free coding service. Did you try google?

Comment: Yes, I searched in google, but I did not found any suitable answer.

Answer (score -1):

use this answer that should get you the source of a html document

[Can Javascript read the source of any web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680562/can-javascript-read-the-source-of-any-web-page)

beside that this is the first link by query google with: page source javascript url

Comment: Sorry, It does not help me.

Comment: could you tell why the solutions you found didn't help?